# Problem with GUI update

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I downloaded the binaries and extracted them. I started the daemon and waited until I was completely synced. Then I opened the wallet and after enetering my password I got the following error message:
Couldn't open wallet: basic_string::_M_replace_aux
What should I do? I'm on windows 64bit

Answer (score 2):

I answered this on Reddit. Basically this error is caused by an incompatible wallet cache, which results in the GUI not being able to open the wallet. Therefore, one has to "trick" the GUI into creating a new, compatible wallet cache. This is done as follows:

1. Exit the GUI.
2. Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero\<wallet-name>` on Windows | `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` on Linux | `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` Mac OS X).
3. Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension, i.e., the wallet cache) to `<wallet-name>-old`
4. Restart the GUI. This will trigger a *wallet* refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

dEBRUYNE_1 answerred me on reddit:

1. Exit the GUI
2. Browse to the directory your wallet files are located and rename "wallet-name" (the file without extension (the wallet cache)) to "wallet-name"-old.
3. Restart the GUI.

For those on windows 64bit:

Your wallet files are located in Documents/Monero. There are three wallet files, namely "wallet-name" (this is the wallet cache), "wallet-name".keys, and "wallet-name".address. You should rename "wallet-name" to "wallet-name"-old. Subsequently, restart the GUI